# RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable - Docker image

Tags: docker, .net-core, rabbitmq

I have installed [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) rabbitmq image ( tag : rabbitmq:3-management )

Used below command to setup container on my machine

```
docker run --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

I can see container is up and running using `docker ps` command

[image: ra]

RabbitMQ management portal is also up and running on port 8080

[image]

**.Net Core 2.2 code**

Below is piece of .Net core code to connect to create a connection

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        factory.Port = 8080;
        factory.UserName = "guest";
        factory.Password = "guest";

        //Getting exception while creating connection 
        //RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

        using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
        }

        //I am having similar issue with MassTransit
        //var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        //{
        //  cfg.Host(new Uri(@"rabbitmq://localhost:8080/my-rabbit"), host =>
        //   {
        //       host.Username("guest");
        //       host.Password("guest");
        //   });
        //});

        //bus.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I am not able to create a connection and getting below exception:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

Do I need to configure container with any other command or pass any additional environment variable while creating container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expose the queue port as well:

```
-p 5672:5672
```

Connect to this port instead of 8080 as you did.